# Oracle can't drop index with . in name?

Tags: oracle, index

I am trying to drop an index that has a dot(.) in its name and can't seem to do it (I'm logged in as the SYSTEM user, which owns the index).  Any ideas?

```
SQL> select index_name,owner,status from all_indexes where owner<>table_owner;

INDEX_NAME                     OWNER                STATUS
------------------------------ -------------------- --------------------
IX_isbn_send_h.D_STAT          SYSTEM               VALID

SQL> drop index IX_isbn_send_h.D_STAT;
drop index IX_isbn_send_h.D_STAT
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01418: specified index does not exist
```

Comment: Use quotation marks, @par!

Comment: I had tried single-quotes and that didn't work.  For some reason putting it in double-quotes did.  Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Comment: @par nevermind :) yep, you should use double quotes when refer to an object name and single quotes to indicate a character or string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one:

```
DROP INDEX SYSTEM."IX_isbn_send_h.D_STAT";
```

Note, when you use quotes, then names are case-sensitive in Oracle.